# Creating data.frame of multiple random samples from a vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, random, sample

I have the vector `X` and I would like to generate a `data.frame` of 6 integer samples of size 4. In other words, I would like to have a `data.frame` of 6 * 4 dimension. I tried the following the following but its throwing out lenght argument error.

```
set.seed(123)

X <- c(4,10,15,100,50,31,311,225,85,91)

S <- replicate(X, sample.int(n = 6, size = 4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need

```
replicate(4, sample(X, size = 6))
```

Or

```
replicate(6, sample(X, size = 4))
```

Comment: not sure why? but it doesn't take sample from the Vector `X`

Comment: @Hydro Not clear.  It is taking samples on my console from X though `sample(X, size = 6)#
[1]  85 100  31 225  15   4
> sample(X, size = 6)#
[1]  31  10   4  85 100  50`

Comment: Oopps- I was using `sample.int`- thanks for the express response.

Answer (score 2):

Another base R solution.

```
set.seed(123)

X <- c(4,10,15,100,50,31,311,225,85,91)

dat <- as.data.frame(lapply(1:4, function(i) sample(X, size = 6))) %>%
  setNames(paste0("V", 1:4))

dat
#    V1  V2  V3  V4
# 1  15  50  50  85
# 2  91 100  15  15
# 3  10  31  85 225
# 4 225 225   4  10
# 5  31   4 100 311
# 6  85  10 311   4
```

Comment: Thanks @www, for providing alternative solution.